# Creating a react-native app for IOS and I have created a Microsoft SQL server, how to connect these two?

Tags: javascript, sql, react-native

I have an app built on react native and I want to connect to a database that i have made on the Microsoft SQL server. I have searched online and there are things like myssql but I still get errors with that. I followed this tutorial [nodejs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-2017) from the official Microsoft website, and it works with the nodejs and I use node to run it, but how can i use this in my react native project?

Comment: You need a web service on the machine that runs the SQL server and write an API. Use nodejs, or PHP, or any other suitable language. Your app makes an HTTP request to the API which makes the DB query. The API then returns the result, typically as JSON. Your app receives the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[AXIOS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)** to make requests to your **NodeJS Server**

***In Android*** you can access your localhost by the IP **10.0.2.2** (default proxy configured in your Android Virtual Device).

***In iOS* you can just use localhost**

> Remember to add the port assigned your **NodeJS Server** and the
>   protocol **http**
>
> ***Example URL for Android:*** http://10.0.2.2:3000

Comment: I dont have a nodeJS server though, I have a microsoft SQL server

Comment: Right, so you need a server side to manage your SQL database. You can’t access the database directly from you app

Answer (score 0):

You need to write back-end service code.I suggest you to use Asp.Net Web API .You can use Entity Framework.
Also you can use PHP,Java or Python...

---